# Spring Security for SOAP web services- Token based authentication

Tags: spring, soap, spring-security, spring-ws

I'm developing SOAP web services using **spring-ws framework** and it is required to implement authentication for web service access.I'm trying to implement token based authentication as follows.

1. There is a separate web method to user authentication. If user credentials are valid, system generated token will be returned to the client. Token will have limited validity period.
2. When user accessing rest of the web methods, its required to provide username with the valid token which is returned by the authentication method.
3. Once the token expired, user need to get the valid token again and again through the authentication web service.

Please advice, what are the available methods in spring framework to implement such a scenario. Since I'm newer to spring web-service security, its better if I can have simple guideline on how to implement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can use [Wss4jSecurityInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/wss4j/Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.html) - an `EndpointInterceptor` which can be used to perform security operations on request messages (of course before calling the Endpoint)

```
<bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
  <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken Encrypt" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I need another advice. I want to know how to add customise token to soap response header programmatically rather than setting a property.

Comment: Create a new Interceptor extending [EndpointInterceptorAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/EndpointInterceptor.html) and in the handleResponse method you could add your custom header. Have a look at this [question](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/96724-spring-ws-add-custom-soap-header)